# Retrieve location from Firebase and put marker on google map api for android application

Tags: android, firebase, dictionary, marker

I'm creating a online mess application where there are two logins one for mess owner and another for user so when mess owner put location in his data there should be marker on map in user side.

here is structure of database in image[Database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNDCO.png)

please suggest me code to access those latitude n longitude values and create marker on map for each mess registered with location values.

Comment: You can get the data from the DB and use `LatLng place = new LatLng(mProviderLatitude, mProviderLongitude);`. Then just `googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(place).title("Marker"));` `googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(place));`

Comment: Also, I would suggest you to use Firestore, it has an explicit object type inside the DB for location (i.e. Latitude and longitude are queried at once as an object)

Comment: I did the same code but it is not creating any marker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED
Am proposing a small adjustment to the database structure...under 'MessProviders' create another node called 'locations' with the userID,mProviderLatitude,mProviderLongitude, mProviderBrandName.
  [image: Dbstructure] . 
It would be good if you had a separate class for getters and setters. My class for that is 'CordinatesModel'

```
private void messLocation() {
DatabaseReference currentDBcordinates = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("MessProviders").child("locations");
    currentDBcordinates.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            //Create an array of markers
            int size = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount(); //
            Marker[] allMarkers = new Marker[size];
            mMap.clear();   //Assuming you're using mMap 
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
               //Specify your model class here
                CordinatesModel cordinatesModel = new CordinatesModel();
                //lets create a loop
                 for(int i=0;i<=size;i++) {
                    try {
                        //assuming you've set your getters and setters in the Model class
                          cordinatesModel.setmProviderLatitude(s.getValue(CordinatesModel.class).getmProviderLatitude());
                        cordinatesModel.setmProviderLongitude(s.getValue(CordinatesModel.class).getmProviderLongitude());
                        cordinatesModel.setmProviderBrandName(s.getValue(CordinatesModel.class).getmProviderBrandName());
                        //lets retrieve the coordinates and other information
                         Double latitude1 = cordinatesModel.getmProviderLatitude();
                Double longitude1 = cordinatesModel.getmProviderLongitude();
                String brandName=cordinatesModel.getmProviderBrandName();
                        //convert the coordinates to LatLng
                        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude1, longitude1);
                        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                        //Now lets add updated markers

                     //lets add updated marker
                        allMarkers[i] = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)).position(latLng).title(brandName));enter code here
                 }catch (Exception ex){}
                 }


           }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
 }
```

Comment: I tried this code but It didn't work. you can have look at my project code here https://github.com/Codie8/AutomatedMess1.git

Comment: Hello....Am using the above code in another project and is working, Ok..Let me look at the project and give you the feedback.

Comment: okay try this code in my project and let me know what happens and thank you so much for giving your valuable time.

Comment: Where's the code! Av seen your project, am working on it right now and i will propose some slight changes to the database structure and edit my first answer.

Comment: I'm getting this error " com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found conflicting getters for name: isChangingConfigurations "

Comment: Its because the getters used in the code are not similar to the Fields found in firebase.... I had updated your code on git....

Comment: Or your Database reference points to a different node where the fields you plan on  retrieving are not found

Comment: Thanks you so much I got the solution

Comment: thats the link, try and do something on customer authentication

Comment: Am glad i helped! Happy coding!

Comment: but I'm having problem creating marker for all messProviders

Comment: Can i do it for you and post on github...because one thing i noted on your code; is that you need to move to a new location(physically) so that you can sign-up as a new mess owner and click on the map for it to register the new mess location in the database!

Comment: I have put one answer for my this question please have look at it so that you will get exactly what i want, I've mentioned problem in description.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a root and select it. Then Retrieve all your lat/lng in your snapshot within that root. Here is a sample code:

```
DatabaseReference locationRef = mRootRef.child("locations");
locationRef.addValueEventListener(new com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


        for (DataSnapshot snapm: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

            Double latitude = snapm.child("0").getValue(Double.class);
            Double longitude = snapm.child("1").getValue(Double.class);
            }
        }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
        throw firebaseError.toException();

    }
});
```

Comment: what is that " Firebase" in first line ? it shows error in program.

Comment: Firebase is not even used now. It's old. Editing now.

Answer (score 0):

```
 mDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("MessProviders").child("zZvkbgUbFohCwtYRfORUM0DBSZR2").child("ProfileInformation");
        mDb.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String name = dataSnapshot.child("mProviderBrandName").getValue(String.class);
                    double latt = dataSnapshot.child("mProviderLatitude").getValue(Double.class);
                    double lngg = dataSnapshot.child("mProviderLongitude").getValue(Double.class);
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latt, lngg)).title(name));

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

this is the code that worked to put marker on map but problem is I'm providing user id manually so i will create only one marker but i want to create marker for every user how can system will take user id and create marker for each user id ??

Comment: Using the code i gave you! Go to firebase under locations node! Manually add another brandName and respective longitude and latitude! Add several locations for testing purposes...then check your map on the customer side!   In the meantime let me check the code again!

Comment: I've added a new method onMapReady i.e. setOnMapClickListener which allows you to click anywhere on the map, this in turn calls another method i've defined known as markers(), that allows markers to be placed at any particular point and picks the points longitude and latitude.