# Having a very difficult time populating my map with my json Firebase data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I am trying to grab data(lat and long) from Firebase and place it as markers to populate my Google map. I am using Kotlin.

[jsonFirebaseData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzVEw.png)

I have tried the official Firebase documentation to read data, as well as tried:

http://myfirebasemaps.ga/

Also tried:

[Retrieve location from Firebase and put marker on google map api for android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49324085/retrieve-location-from-firebase-and-put-marker-on-google-map-api-for-android-app)

```
private lateinit var mCompanies: DatabaseReference
```

onCreate section:

```
mCompanies = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
```

onMapReady section:

```
        fun loadMarkersFromDB() {
            mCompanies = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("results")
            mCompanies.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {

                override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    for (s in dataSnapshot.children) {
                        var company = dataSnapshot.getValue(Company::class.java)
                        var location = LatLng(company!!.latitude, company.longitude!!)
                        mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(location).title(company!!.name).snippet(company!!.city))
                            .setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW))
                    }
                }

                override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                    Log.w("MapsActivity", databaseError.toException())
                }
            })
        }
```

Also I have a data class:

```
data class Company(
    var city: String,
    var latitude: Double,
    var longitude: Double,
    var name: String
) {
    constructor() : this("", 0.0, 0.0, "")
}
```

Nothing happens. App does not crash, but no markers gets added from my firebase.

**EDIT**

I created a private function:

```
    private fun loadMarkersFromDB() {
        mCompanies = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
        mCompanies.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    for (s in dataSnapshot.children) {
                        var company = dataSnapshot.getValue(Company::class.java)
                        var location = LatLng(company!!.latitude, company.longitude!!)
                        mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(location).title(company!!.name).snippet(company!!.city))
                            .setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW))
                        Log.d("onDataChange", company.toString())
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                Log.w("MapsActivity", databaseError.toException())
            }
        })
    }
```

Then I call the function in onMapReady after the map has been created.

```
Log.d("onDataChange", company.toString())
```

displays this on Logcat:

```
D/onDataChange: Company(city=, latitude=0.0, longitude=0.0, name=)
```

When I change it to **company!!.city** nothing shows up.

Comment: Is your `onDataChange()` even triggered? If you try to log the name of the city, is it printed out in the logcat?

Comment: Hi, just tried it and it looks like nothing is showing up in logcat

Comment: Does `Log.w("MapsActivity", databaseError.toException())` print something?

Comment: No, nothing shows up in Logcat

Comment: If y our `onDataChange` is not called, are you sure you are connected to the internet?

Comment: yes, I also tried to set permissions in manifest as well, but nothing happens

Comment: In your case, I think it's either a permission issue or you are not connected to the internet.

Comment: Hello, so I finally manage to get something out of onDataChange:

D/onDataChange: Company(city=, latitude=0.0, longitude=0.0, name=)

That's only when I log my data class and convert it to a toString()

But aside from that, I can't get anything else

Comment: Please show us where you have added the log statement?

Comment: I added it inside the for loop

for (s in dataSnapshot.children) {
                        var company = dataSnapshot.getValue(Company::class.java)
                        var location = LatLng(company!!.latitude, company.longitude!!)
                        mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(location).title(company!!.name).snippet(company!!.city))
                            .setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW))
                        Log.d("onDataChange", company.toString())
                    }

Comment: Please add it to your question so it can be well formated.

Comment: Added, also modified my code a bit, to see if it would help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't getting anything because your reference points to the root node and not to the `results` node. To sovle this, simply change the following line of code:

```
mCompanies.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(/* ... */)
```

to

```
mCompanies.child("data").child("results").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(/* ... */)
```

Comment: ok I changed it to this however I still get nothing on the map, and now my logcat is also blank with:

Log.d("onDataChange", company.toString())

also tried

Log.d("onDataChange", company!!.city)

and I get nothing still.

Comment: `data` node is your root node? Or do you have any other nodes? If you have, please add another more detailed screenshot.

Comment: I have the project name at the very top and followed by data then results

Comment: If you have the `data` node between the root node and `results` node, it should also be added with child call as in my updated answer. Does it work now?